# keep my sort after updating the dataprovider's data

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I have a datagrid where the data in the dataprovider changes every 30 seconds automatically. Everytime it does, if I chose to sort the column by clicking on the header, it will revert back to the default sort (before I clicked on the header). I want to know how I can control the sorting so that if I had clicked on it previously, it will remain sorted as so the next 30 seconds.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="id" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <mx:columns>
                            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@col1" headerText="Type1" itemRenderer="itemRenderer" />
                            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@col2" headerText="Type2" itemRenderer="itemRenderer" />
                        </mx:columns>
                        <mx:dataProvider>
                            {xmllist_extractedfromAnotherSourceEvery30Seconds}
                        </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess... The sort order is stored within the dataProvider (ArrayCollection), and it gets lost when you re-assign a new dataProvider.

You could either:

- update the dataProvider using ArrayCollection update functions,
  instead of re-assigning it
- if not possible, [get the ISort](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#sort) from the dataProvider before changing it; then apply this ISort to the new dataProvider after
  loading (and remember to refresh() the dataProvider)

Comment: Hm I'm having trouble working either of the 2 proposals just because I'm limited with how much of the code I am allowed to modify. What I was hoping for is to store a boolean that says the sort button on the top of the column was or was not clicked and just set it clicked the next time it refreshes. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately if you don't have control of the dataProvider, you won't be able to control the sort.

Comment: regarding your second option, could you show me code implementation?

Comment: I retrieved an old post (but still valid) that describes an implementation of the second approach: https://justinjmoses.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/flex-keeping-the-sort-on-a-datagrid-when-you-change-the-dataprovider/